# How to export my entire Google Scholar Library in BibTex

Tags: export, google-scholar

I want to export my entire Google Scholar Library into a BibTex in one click or by some other clever ways which I don't know about. At present, I can only export at max 10 articles in one go and I need to move to subsequent pages and repeat the process. My Library is huge hence, I was wondering if there is a clever way (by running some scripts etc.) to achieve just that?

[image: Google Scholar - My Library]